# Dead code warning?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Why am I getting a dead code warning on the i++ in this function ?

```
InputFilter hexInputFilter()
    {
    return new InputFilter()
        {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                    int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
                {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
                    {
                    if ((source.charAt(i) >= '0')
                            && (source.charAt(i) <= '9'))
                        {
                        return null;
                        }
                    if ((Character.toUpperCase(source.charAt(i)) >= 'A')
                            && (Character.toUpperCase(source.charAt(i)) <= 'F'))
                        {
                        return null;
                        }
                    return "";
                    }
                return null;
                }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Added 'java' tag, since this question is more closer to Java than Android.

Comment: Solved by moving the return ""; outside of the loop and removing the final return null; Thanks all for the quick answers

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's no chance for the `for` to loop more than once because you are returning:

```
return "";
```

Thus, `i++` won't be executed ever and that's why you get a *dead code* warning. Maybe you want to remove that `return "";` and/or put it outside the `for`.

Comment: You are right, the return ""; was suposed to be outside of the loop. Now that I know about it it is jumping in my face :o)  Thanks

Answer (score 13):

That is because `i++` is normally executed after the end of the for-block, and in your function the end of the for-block will never be reached because in the block you unconditionally return a value.

A for-loop

```
for (A; B; C) {
  D;
}
```

is internally translated into the following:

```
A;
while (B) {
  D;  
  C;
}
```

You can see that if `D` always returns from the function, `C` will never be reached. That's what the complaint is about.

Answer (score 5):

You'll only ever execute the loop once because of the `return "";` statement.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the below statement is causing the problem as it runs unconditionally and will always run when the for loop is executed. So it will never reach for i++ so its dead code.

```
return "";
```